# Better heuristics to discard faces in images of sports competitions

Tags: computer-vision, heuristics

I am currently working on a problem of re-identification of athletes in sports competitions, I have a large dataset of images like this:

[runners and public](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6tBX.jpg)

We are using [retinafaces](https://github.com/biubug6/Pytorch_Retinaface) for face detection, and some heuristics to discard the faces of the audience and get only the runners,the heuristics I'm working with are:

1. Use the score that retinafaces gives us -> very bad heuristic
2. Use the size of the face to choose the largest or those that are greater than a certain threshold -> sounds good but it's bad
3. Use the distance of the face from the center of the image. -> sounds good but it's bad
4. Combinations between them -> the best but not very good

I was wondering if anyone has worked with a similar problem or knows of any creative solutions for this.(We have more models to detect faces but the same thing happens with all of us)

Thank you for reading!

Comment: sounds like retinafaces is a bad detector, or your data is worse than they trained their model for. your example picture has severe motion blur due to the camera having to deal with a low light situation. I would recommend talking to the authors of the retinafaces paper and repository.